Does using BSD 3 or MIT licensed code in my commercial code/application allow reverse engineering of my closed source code/application?
I write commercial code and sometimes use MIT or BSD 3 licensed code I find on github for instance.
Recently somebody told me I need to be careful as some of these 'open source' licenses, like LGPL for instance, allows the users of my closed source code to reverse engineer my (closed source) code. Lucky for me I knew that using LGPL code was not 'the right deal' for me, but I do use open source code with other license types (mainly MIT and BSD-3).
I have looked everywhere I could think of and also at fossa.com, but the option in the licenses about reverse engineering is not always clear/mentioned.
So, my question is : if I use code with an MIT or BSD-3 license and release my code under a commercial license, neither directly nor indirectly is it allowed by users of my (closed source) code/application to reverse engineer my code/application ?

The rights and obligations of a licensee w.r.t. reverse engineering depend on the jurisdiction and circumstances. It does not (not directly) depend on the OSS licenses of the components included in your works, especially when you use code with permissive licenses. That might be the reason why you could non find anything specific about 'open source reverse engineering.

The person who told you about reverse engineering is incorrect. There are no open-source licenses that explicitly allow the recipient of a binary distribution to reverse engineer the code, especially not code that wasn't distributed under an open-source license.
Open-source licenses come on a spectrum, ranging from permissive to weak copyleft to strong copyleft. The common denominator for open-source licenses is that they give people who receive the code under the terms of an open-source license the right to make changes and to re-distribute the code with or without changes.
Permissive licenses, like MIT and BSD, are written with the idea to give the direct recipient of the code a lot of freedom, including the freedom to re-distribute the code under a closed-source license. The simple fact that you received something under, for example, the MIT license, does not imply in any way that the recipient of your product gets any modification rights.
Strong copyleft licenses, like GPL and AGPL, have the requirement that if one part of a project is subject to the license, then the complete project must be provided under the terms of the same strong copyleft license. Those terms also include a requirement to provide source code, so reverse engineering of a binary should not be needed. The aim of these licenses is to give as much freedom as possible to the end-users.
Weak copyleft licenses, like LGPL and MPL, are a bit of a middle ground. Code that you received or placed under a weak copyleft license needs to remain under the copyleft license and source code must be provided for those parts. But the license also allows the copyleft part to be combined with closed-source parts. The LGPL is the strongest of these licenses with its requirement that the end-user must be able to use the product with a modified version of the LGPL parts. If you don't pay attention during development, this requirement can force you to disclose object code of the closed source portions, so the end-user can re-link them to the LGPL portions. Reverse engineering of the closed-source parts is still not allowed.

To be complete, the law may permit reverse engineering for certain purposes. Those you cannot prevent or forbid with your license terms. This is independent of what 3rd-party components you use and what licenses they have.
For example, in the EU it is by law allowed to do limited forms of reverse engineering to provide interoperability between products of different vendors.

The LGPL 3.0 does have specific language that says that you may not forbid "reverse
engineering for debugging such modifications" but if you read the whole paragraph, I think it's referring specifically to the LGPL parts of the application only. Basically I think the intention is to say that you can't put in prevention mechanisms that prevents a user from modifying the LGPL part of the application. But I wouldn't read it as saying that you're not allowed to add such restrictions to your own non-LGPL code if you wish.

@Brandin That was exactly what this person was talking about on the topic of LGPL and he said that it is a very gray area wether or not it implies on only the modifications or not. He said it is certainly open for discussion. I presume that it might have been a combination of what you are talking about and the EU law with limited form of reverse engineering Bart was talking about. That would explain his version !

@BartvanIngenSchenau Thanks for the clear and well outlined response. I used to think that I was within my rights using the MIT and BSD licensed code, but thanks to the person mentioning 'the possible problems', I wondered if I missed some angle. All of you have been most helpful !

This answer gives the impression that it's illegal to reverse-engineer a program obtained under any open-source license (MIT, BSD, GPL, etc.)... is that really true? I would be surprised to find so.

@DavidZ, Reverse engineering is allowed to the extent that the law allows it. (Most) open-source licenses do not contain a clause to give more rights in that respect than given by law. Where relevant to the philosophy of the license drafters, they do contain clauses that largely remove the need for reverse engineering.

@DavidZ This Answer states "there are no open source licenses which allow ..." which I read to mean "there is not an open source license that says 'reverse engineering is hereby allowed'". A license only needs to give you permission to do the things that you're otherwise not allowed to do.

I get that that's what was intended, but that's not how I read it. In order to convey the intended meaning to me, it would need to be phrased something more like "There are no open-source licenses that explicitly allow the recipient of a binary distribution to reverse engineer the code, because there is no need for them to do so: reverse engineering is already legal by default."

I don't disagree with Bart's answer, but I'd like to come at the question from a different direction.
Reverse-engineering is not generally per se illegal.  Different jurisdictions have different degrees of protection/proscription for it, some of which are outlined on Wikipedia.
Some jurisdictions, notably the US, maintain that it's not a violation of copyright, but if the licence requires that you not do it, doing so can be a breach of the licence terms.  Hence, many proprietary software licences require you to agree not to do it in order to purchase a software licence.  The EU, on the other hand, specifically protects the right; this from Article 5 of directive 2009/24/EC:

The person having a right to use a copy of a computer program shall be entitled, without the authorisation of the rightholder, to observe, study or test the functioning of the program in order to determine the ideas and principles which underlie any element of the program if he does so while performing any of the acts of loading, displaying, running, transmitting or storing the program which he is entitled to do.

Free software takes a different path.  One of the four freedoms is the "freedom to study how the program works, and change it so it does your computing as you wish", and moreover "access to the source code is a precondition for this".  So free software not only protects your right to reverse-engineer, but seeks to bend over backwards so you won't need to.  You are not, therefore, going to find any kind of free licence that restricts reverse-engineering.
In answer to your specific question: if you take code released under a permissive free licence (which includes MIT and BSD3) and incorporate it into a product, and you licence that product under proprietary terms which forbid reverse-engineering, then those users in jurisdictions where that right is not otherwise protected will be (at least theoretically) in breach of the terms of the licence should they do so, and further (unlicensed) use of the code would arguably be a violation of your copyright.

Hi @MadHatter I marked the answer of Bart as the correct one, but I do find your remarks most helpful, so I up voted. Specifically, the notion of 'forbid reverse engineering' is a nice addition !
